# Burninate [creating] and [created]

Tags: feature-request, burninate-request

The [creating](/questions/tagged/creating) tag doesn't seem to add any value to the site. This tag has questions on many topics: creating arrays, creating websites, creating methods, ...
It also doesn't have a tag wiki.

Should this tag be burninated?

[Edit]

I also noticed that there's a tag [created](/questions/tagged/created). I think this tag should also be burninated for the same reasons.

Comment: Burninating all the gerunds!

Comment: @JoachimSauer leave [tag:having] as it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: @Szymon: I'm pretty sure there is a decent amount of sensible exceptions, but "Burninating a significant portion of the gerunds!" just doesn't have the same ring to it ;-) Also: all absolutes are wrong!

Comment: Whilst you're at it [tag:creativity] is small and every question pretty much needs closing or deleting. If someone has some spare votes that'd be good (don't remove the tag as it's useful for pointing at the questions).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Am I the only one that sees the paradox in your last assertion?

Comment: @Cruncher: I sincerely hope that you're not the only one.

Comment: @JoachimSauer After thinking about it, it may not actually be a paradox. Sure if it's true, then it must be false, but it being false doesn't imply it's true, unless it were the only absolute statement. I think that the statement is actually just false. x < x+1 seems like an absolute to me, by defintion.

Comment: If it's false, i.e. "All absolutes are correct", then the absolute "All absolutes are wrong" must be true, which means it's a paradox surely @Cruncher?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards the negation of "All absolutes are wrong" is "At least one absolute is correct" NOT "All absolutes are correct". The negation of a universal statement is an existential one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#Negation

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards "I solved every problem" This is clearly false. Therefore "I solved no problems"? No, however, "There is a problem that I didn't solve" is correct.

Comment: Well, personally I don't think that statement needs to be a paradox to be effective, it simply needs to be self-defeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the last of them. The tags [creating](/questions/tagged/creating) and [created](/questions/tagged/created) have been burned.

[image]